# Powershell add text after 20 characters

Tags: powershell

I want to add text after exactly 20 characters inklusiv blanks. Does someone have a short solution with add-content or can post a link where i can read about a way to do so.

My file looks somthing like this:

```
/path1/path1/path1              /path2/path2/path2         /path3/path3/path3
```

than an application will read this pahts (not my application and i can not edit it in any way) the application will read these paths and it will read them on their position so if the second path starts 10 characters later it wont recognize it, so i can not simply replace the path or edit it easy sinc the path has not always the same lenght. Why the application reads it that way dont ask me.

So i need to add a string at start than the next string at exactly character 20 and than the next at charcter 40.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me

```
$data.PadRight(20," ") | Out-File -FilePath F:\test\path.txt -NoNewline -Append
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the regex `-replace` operator to inject a new substring after 20 characters:

```
PS ~> $inject = "Hello Manuel! ..."
PS ~> $string = "Injected text goes: and then there's more"
PS ~> $string -replace '(?<=^.{20})',$inject
Injected text goes: Hello Manuel! ...and then there's more
```

The regex pattern `(?<=^.{20})` describes a position in the string where exactly 20 characters occur between the start of the string and the current position, and the `-replace` operator then replaces the empty string at said position with the value in `$inject`

Comment: Hello this is interesting, i can actually use this for another problem i have but for now it doesnt work for what i need, my fault my question is not that accurate. I will edit my question.